# the 2-D divergence theorem and Green's Theorem

Tags: integration, greens-theorem

I read somewhere that the 2-D Divergence Theorem is the same as the Green's Theorem.
So for Green's theorem
$$\oint_{\partial \Omega} {\textbf{F}} \cdot d {\textbf{S}} = \iint_{\Omega} \text{2d-curl}{\textbf{F}} \, d\Omega$$
and also by Divergence (2-D) Theorem,
$$\oint_{\partial \Omega} {\textbf{F}} \cdot d {\textbf{S}} = \iint_{\Omega} \text{div}{\textbf{F}} \, d\Omega$$.
Since they can evaluate the same flux integral, then
$$\iint_{\Omega} \text{2d-curl}{\textbf{F}} \, d\Omega = \int_{\Omega} \text{div}{\textbf{F}} \, d\Omega.$$
Is there an intuition for why the summing of divergence in a region is equal to the summing of the curl in a region in 2-D?

Comment: While the Green's Theorem conciders the dot product of a field $\textbf{F}$ with the *tangent vector* $d\textbf{S}$ to the boundary curve, the divergence therem talks about the dot product with the *unit outward normal* $\textbf{n}$ to the boundary, which are not equal, and hence your last equation is false. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Relationship_to_the_divergence_theorem

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look there. But that means one of my first two equations were incorrect right? (Ah, it would be the first becasue of the dot product?)  
Would it then be equal?

Comment: Also, I thought that in general we could (notationally) simplify ${d\textbf{S}}$ to ${\textbf{n}} \cdot dS$?

Comment: No, one is a contour integral (Green's Theorem) and the other, a surface integral (Gauss Divergence Theorem), so $d{\bf S} \ne {\bf n}dS$ and in fact $ {\bf n}\cdot d{\bf S} =0$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not quite right: they are equivalent, but they don't use the same vector field or the same vector on the boundary. The divergence theorem says
$$ \iint_{\Omega} \operatorname{div}{\mathbf{F}} \, dx \, dy = \oint_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dl, $$
where $\mathbf{n}$ is an outward-pointing normal and $dl$ is the line element. Now, $\mathbf{n} \, dl $ is perpendicular to $d\mathbf{l}$ (being a normal). $d\mathbf{l} = (dx,dy)$, so the outward-pointing normal is $(dy,-dx)$ (rotate it by $\pi/2$ anticlockwise). So if we take $\mathbf{F}=(M,-L)$, we find this becomes
$$ \iint_{\Omega} \left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} \right) dx \, dy = \oint_{\partial\Omega} (-L) \,(-dx) +M \, dy, $$
which is Green's theorem.

What's actually going on here is that in two dimensions, $\operatorname{curl}{\mathbf{F}}$ can be written as the divergence of the field $\mathbf{F}_{\perp} = (F_2,-F_1)$, the rotation of $\mathbf{F}$ through a right angle. So
$$ \oint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{l} \stackrel{\text{Stokes}}{=} \iint_{\Omega} \operatorname{curl}{\mathbf{F}} \, dx \, dy = \iint_{\Omega} \operatorname{div}{\mathbf{F}_{\perp}} \, dx \, dy \stackrel{\text{div thm}}{=} \oint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F}_{\perp} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dl.  $$
We can now also understand the equality between the line integrals by the equality $\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = \mathbf{F}_{\perp} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dl $, since $ \mathbf{n} dl = (d\mathbf{l})_{\perp}$. So what in effect has happened is that both vectors have been rotated by the same amount, and hence the dot product gives the same value: $ \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = \mathbf{F}_{\perp} \cdot (d\mathbf{l})_{\perp} $.

Comment: How do I generalize this in three dimensions? Suppose the curve is described using parametric equations, then I need to solve the entire thing in a parametric form, right ? In that case, we'll have something like a parametric scalar surface integral.

Comment: It's a question which is led to the idea of displacement current in physics. I think it's better to see the physics first, see [this vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZYFYUFRblM) by prof Lewin. (P.s: I do know the controversy behind him, but I still think his lectures are superb) @NakshatraGangopadhay