# Applying Divergence Theorem or an analogue to a Closed Surface Integral

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider $\oint_S({\nabla\cdot\vec{F}})dA$ (the closed surface integral of the divergence of a vector field). Is there a theorem which rewrites this integral as:$$\oint_B{(\vec{F}\cdot \hat{n})dl}$$ Where B is the boundary of the closed surface.

I'd like to emphasize that I'm starting with a closed surface integral. Is the boundary of a closed surface non-existent? What does this mean for evaluating such an integral?

Comment: If you are trying to calculate the flux through a closed surface, you can apply this theorem to the part of the surface above the boundary $l$, and then apply the theorem to the part of the surface below $l$.  Then, add the two results together.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I guess my confusion mainly comes from dealing with a closed surface integral. In my first exposure to divergence theorem, we converted volume integral of the divergence of some vector field to the flux out through a closed surface containing said volume. This intuitively makes sense. However, I cannot visualize/intuit the analogous case for when we are starting with a closed surface integral and trying to convert it into whatever else.

Comment: @SillyGoose, see my comment.  You can separate into two open surfaces and add the results.  You will need to be careful to maintain the same orientation of the boundary curve $l$.

Comment: I think that someone has to tell explicitly in the post above: 1) on what space is the field defined, 2) whether or not A is closed, 3) what is B if A is closed (i.e. has no boundary)

Comment: The boundary of a closed surface is empty, ... or I forgot something

Comment: @Physor could you explain what that means, man?

Comment: @SillyGoose I deleted my initial comment because I realized it's easy to misinterpret what I said, and apply it incorrectly (for example if $F:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^3$ is say $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$, then $\text{div}(F)=3$, and the surface integral over the unit sphere $S$ is non-zero, and $\partial S=\emptyset$. whereas a naive reading of what I wrote might have suggested to you that the result is $0$). In any case, a *closed surface* by definition means a *compact, boundaryless surface* (compact, boundaryless 2-dimensional smooth manifold to be explicit).

Comment: A closed surface (e.g. embedded in $\mathbb R^3$) is a manifold without boundary. So the latter integral is over an empty set and therefore zero

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2301324/568204) is a link which explains in some more detail what I had originally intended to say (though it seems that perhaps this isn't really what you're asking about).